# Playing multi-sampled Instruments using AudioKit, controlling ADSR envelope

Tags: ios, swift, audiotoolbox, audiokit

I'm trying to play instrument of several *.wav* samples using AudioKit.

I've tried so far:

1. Using `AKSampler` (with underlying `AVAudioUnitSampler`) – it worked fine, but I can't figure out how to control ADSR envelope here – calling `stop` will stop note immediately.
2. Another way is to use `AKSamplePlayer` for each sample and play it, manually setting `rate` so it play the right note. I can (possibly?) then connect `AKAmplitudeEnvelope` to each sample player. But if I want to play 5 notes of the same sample simultaneously, I would need 5 instances of `AKSamplePlayer`, which seems like wasting resources.

I also tried to find a way to just push raw audio samples to the AudioKit output buffer, making mixing and sample interpolation by myself (in C, probably?). But didn't find how to do it :(

What is the right way to make a multi-sampled instrument using AudioKit? I feel like it must be a fairly simple task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [mahal tertin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47359088/playing-multi-sampled-instruments-using-audiokit-controlling-adsr-envelope/47359835?noredirect=1#comment81684989_47359835), it's pretty easy to use `AKAUPresetBuilder`!
You can create .aupreset file somewhere in tmp directory and then load this instrument with `AKSampler`.

The only thing worth noting is that by default `AKAUPresetBuilder` will generate samples with trigger mode set to `trigger`, which will ignore note-off events. So you should set it explicitly.

For example:

```
let sampleC4 = AKAUPresetBuilder.generateDictionary(
                    rootNote: 60,
                    filename: pathToC4WavSample,
                    startNote: 48,
                    endNote: 65)
sampleC4["triggerMode"] = "hold"

let sampleC5 = AKAUPresetBuilder.generateDictionary(
                    rootNote: 72,
                    filename: pathToC5WavSample,
                    startNote: 66,
                    endNote: 83)
sampleC5["triggerMode"] = "hold"

AKAUPresetBuilder.createAUPreset(
                    dict: [sampleC4, sampleC5],
                    path: pathToAUPresetFilename,
                    instrumentName: "My Instrument",
                    attack: 0,
                    release: 0.2)
```

and then create a sampler and start AudioKit:

```
sampler = AKSampler()

try sampler.loadInstrument(atPath: pathToAUPresetFilename)

AudioKit.output = sampler
AudioKit.start()
```

and then use this to start playing note:

```
sampler.play(noteNumber: MIDINoteNumber(63), velocity: MIDIVelocity(120), channel: 0)
```

and this to stop, respecting release parameter:

```
sampler.stop(noteNumber: MIDINoteNumber(63), channel: 0)
```

Comment: Upd: things now changed with the new AudioKit's own AKSampler!

Answer (score 2):

Probably the best way would be to embed your wav files into an EXS or Soundfont format, making use of tools in that realm to accomplish the ADSR for instance. Otherwise you'll kind of have to have an instrument for each sample.

Comment: Instruments are user-generated, so I can't make exs24 or soundfont :(  

Maybe it's OK to have an instrument for each sample. But how can I setup the ADSR for the instrument? (I've read I can configure .caf files – but that looks way too complicated, and I have .wav, not .caf).

Comment: Can you send the sampler through an AKADSREnvelope and start and stop it timed appropriately?

Comment: or use aupreset instruments, they can be modified with the parser.

Comment: @AureliusProchazka, yes, I can, but again, it would require 5 samplers for 5 simultaneously played notes – they may end and start at different time :(

Comment: @mahaltertin, could you tell more about the “parser”? Is there any way to dynamically generate aupreset from bunch of .wav samples and then load in into AKSampler/AVAudioUnitSampler?

Comment: it's not trivial and i'm away from Xcode this weekend; this would be a starting point: http://audiokit.io/docs/Classes/AKAUPresetBuilder.html#/s:8AudioKit17AKAUPresetBuilderC14createAUPresetySaySo19NSMutableDictionaryCG4dict_SS4pathSS14instrumentNameSdSg6attackAK7releasetFZ